# Flutter bloc - Event only gets called 2 times inside the bloc logic

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm having problems to send the event in the bloc. The problem I'm having is that when I send the first event the Bloc is getting called and after I recall it again with a diferrent tab and it works, but when I change to another tab the bloc doesn't get called even if the add event is sending. I have checked with the debbuger and when I call it after the 2 first it doesn't get executed the bloc.

Example where I send the event:

```
class ListOpportunitiesList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool showTopIcons, showFilterMarvTypes;
  final OpportunitiesListTypeEnum opportunitiesListTypeEnum;

  const ListOpportunitiesList({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.showTopIcons,
    @required this.showFilterMarvTypes,
    @required this.opportunitiesListTypeEnum,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOpportunitiesListState createState() => _ListOpportunitiesListState();
}

class _ListOpportunitiesListState extends State<ListOpportunitiesList> {
  InvestmentMarvTypeEnum _investmentMarvTypeEnum;
  InvestmentStatusEnum _investmentStatusEnum;

  InvestmentOpportunityBloc investmentOpportunityBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    investmentOpportunityBloc = getIt.getItInstance<InvestmentOpportunityBloc>();
    this.getOpportunities();
  }

  // Calling the event works only the first 2 times
  void getOpportunities() {
    investmentOpportunityBloc.add(
      InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent(
        opportunitiesListTypeEnum: this.widget.opportunitiesListTypeEnum,
        investmentMarvTypeEnum: this._investmentMarvTypeEnum,
        investmentStatusEnum: this._investmentStatusEnum,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    this.investmentOpportunityBloc?.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double topMargin = this.widget.showFilterMarvTypes
        ? height * UIConstants.marginTopPercentageWithFilter
        : height * UIConstants.marginTopPercentage;

    return BlocProvider<InvestmentOpportunityBloc>(
      create: (context) => this.investmentOpportunityBloc,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          CustomAppBar(
            title: '${this.widget.title}',
            showLogged: this.widget.showTopIcons,
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: this.widget.opportunitiesListTypeEnum == OpportunitiesListTypeEnum.all,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: InvestmentMarvTypeEnum.values
                    .map(
                      (e) => SelectableRoundedRectangleButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        this._investmentMarvTypeEnum =
                        this._investmentMarvTypeEnum == e ? null : e;
                      });
                      this.getOpportunities();
                    },
                    selected: e == this._investmentMarvTypeEnum,
                    text:
                    '${InvestmentOpportunityUtility.getMarvTypeString(e)}',
                  ),
                )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BlocBuilder<InvestmentOpportunityBloc, InvestmentOpportunityState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded) {
                if (state.investmentOpportunityModel.isNotEmpty) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      for (InvestmentOpportunityModel opportunity
                          in state.investmentOpportunityModel)
                        InvestmentOpportunityCard(
                          investmentOpportunityModel: opportunity,
                        ),
                      Visibility(
                        visible: !state.hasReachedMax,
                        child: ListBottomLoadingWidget(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return AppEmptyWidget(
                    investmentMarvTypeEnum: this._investmentMarvTypeEnum,
                    topMargin: topMargin,
                    uiEmptyTypeEnum: UIEmptyTypeEnum.investment_opportunity,
                  );
                }
              } else if (state is InvestmentOpportunityError) {
                return AppErrorWidget(
                  topMargin: topMargin,
                  apiNetworkException: state.apiError,
                  retryButton: () => this.getOpportunities(),
                );
              } else {
                return AppLoadingWidget(
                  topMargin: topMargin,
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the bloc logic:

```
class InvestmentOpportunityBloc
    extends Bloc<InvestmentOpportunityEvent, InvestmentOpportunityState> {
  final GetInvestmentOpportunities getInvestmentOpportunities;
  final GetInvestedInvestmentOpportunities getInvestedInvestmentOpportunities;
  final GetFavorites getFavorites;
  List<InvestmentOpportunityModel> listOpportunity;

  InvestmentOpportunityBloc({
    @required this.getInvestmentOpportunities,
    @required this.getInvestedInvestmentOpportunities,
    @required this.getFavorites,
  }) : super(InvestmentOpportunityInitial());

  @override
  Stream<InvestmentOpportunityState> mapEventToState(
    InvestmentOpportunityEvent event,
  ) async* {
    final currentState = state;

    if (event is InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent || event is InvestmentOpportunityChangeTab) {
      bool modifyType = false;

      if (currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded) {
        switch ((event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).opportunitiesListTypeEnum) {
          case OpportunitiesListTypeEnum.invested:
            {
              modifyType = (event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).investmentStatusEnum !=
                  currentState
                      .investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO.investmentStatusEnum;
            }
            break;
          case OpportunitiesListTypeEnum.all:
            {
              modifyType = (event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).investmentMarvTypeEnum !=
                  currentState.investmentOpportunityDTO.investmentMarvTypeEnum;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (!modifyType && this._hasReachedMax(currentState)) {
          return;
        }
      }

      InvestmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO;
      InvestmentOpportunityDTO investmentOpportunityDTO;

      Either<ApiNetworkException, List<InvestmentOpportunityModel>>
          opportunityEither;

      switch ((event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).opportunitiesListTypeEnum) {
        case OpportunitiesListTypeEnum.invested:
          {
            if (currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded && !modifyType) {
              currentState.investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO.pageDTO
                  .incrementPage();
              investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO =
                  currentState.investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO;
            } else {
              yield InvestmentOpportunityInitial();
              investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO =
                  InvestmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO(
                pageDTO: PageDTO(),
                investmentStatusEnum: (event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).investmentStatusEnum,
              );
            }

            opportunityEither = await this.getInvestedInvestmentOpportunities(
                investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO);
          }
          break;
        case OpportunitiesListTypeEnum.all:
          {
            if (currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded && !modifyType) {
              currentState.investmentOpportunityDTO.pageDTO.incrementPage();
              investmentOpportunityDTO = currentState.investmentOpportunityDTO;
            } else {

              yield InvestmentOpportunityInitial();
              investmentOpportunityDTO = InvestmentOpportunityDTO(
                pageDTO: PageDTO(),
                investmentMarvTypeEnum: (event as InvestmentOpportunityLoadEvent).investmentMarvTypeEnum,
              );
            }
            opportunityEither =
                await this.getInvestmentOpportunities(investmentOpportunityDTO);
          }
          break;
      }

      yield opportunityEither.fold(
        (error) => InvestmentOpportunityError(error),
        (opportunities) {
          if (currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded &&
              opportunities.isEmpty) {
            return currentState.copyWith(hasReachedMax: true);
          }

          this.listOpportunity = currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded && !modifyType
              ? currentState.investmentOpportunityModel + opportunities
              : opportunities;

          return InvestmentOpportunityLoaded(
            investmentOpportunityModel: this.listOpportunity,
            investmentOpportunityDTO: investmentOpportunityDTO,
            investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO:
                investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO,
            hasReachedMax: BlocUtility.hasReachedMax(
              opportunities.length,
              investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO != null
                  ? investmentsOpportunitiesInvestedDTO.pageDTO.take
                  : investmentOpportunityDTO.pageDTO.take,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else if (event is InvestmentOpportunityUpdateStatusOfInvestment &&
        currentState is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded) {
      currentState.investmentOpportunityModel[currentState
              .investmentOpportunityModel
              .indexOf(event.investmentOpportunityModel)] =
          event.investmentOpportunityModel;

      yield currentState.copyWith(
        investmentOpportunityModel: currentState.investmentOpportunityModel,
      );
    }
  }

  bool _hasReachedMax(InvestmentOpportunityState state) {
    return state is InvestmentOpportunityLoaded && state.hasReachedMax;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the the bloc's close method in the dispose method? Bloc with automatically close on their own with the widget that is providing it is disposed. Make sure that your bloc isn't disposed or else your bloc can't receive any new events.

Comment: [Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403726) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66858287) saying "How have you registered the InvestmentOpportunityBloc in getIt. Are you using a register factory?"